# How to remove the password of HC-05 Bluetooth Module?

Tags: bluetooth, passwords, at-command, hc-05

I want to build an app in which a user can connect with Bluetooth to the HC-05 Bluetooth Module. 
Is there a chance to disable/remove the password of the HC-05 Bluetooth Module with AT-Commands? So that the user only clicks the Device-Name in the app and then he's connected.

I already tried to configure the Module with AT-Commands like: `AT+PSWD=`, but that won't work.

Thanks for your help!